# “Whose” Vs “Its”?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is there any difference when using whose or its?

- It gives a mapping from the path and whose derivative to system controls.
- It gives a mapping from the path and its derivative to system controls.

Comment: Both words are completely different in meaning and usage. The first sentence is grammatically incorrect. The second sentence is okay.

Comment: I agree with DG - although there is some overlap.  "I can see a window whose glass is broken" means almost the same thing as "I can see a window. Its glass is broken".  (The main difference is that the first version might suggest you could see multiple windows, only one broken. So a closer equiv. wd. be "I can see a window with broken glass.") So in some cases you can switch between the two, although it usually means switching between one sentence and two sentences. (It's also rare in ordinary conversation to use "whose" to refer to an inanimate object, though it's perfectly correct usage.)

Comment: The _and_ before _whose_  is the problem. Where does the sentence come from?

Comment: @rjpond thank youu, I get it now

Comment: @KateBunting I just wrote myself and got into this problem :)